# vim find and replace over multiple lines, excluding more than a character

Tags: regex, vim, latex

I would like to find structures of the type

```
\be
 something
\ee
```

in my LaTeX file and replace them with

```
\begin{comment}
\be
 something
\ee
\end{comment}
```

. The most similar thing I could come up with was

```
:%s/\\be\(\_[^\]*\)\\ee/\\begin{comment}\r\\be\1\\ee\r\\end{comment}/g
```

However, if something includes e.g. \frac{1}{2}, this does not work anymore. So how do I
perform this replacement correctly? I.e., how do I exclude \ee (and not just \) from the body between \be and \ee?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is `something` just one line?

Comment: @Shahbaz I guess not, he did used `\_[^\]`

Comment: @kent, I was just now searching what `\_` means!

Comment: Here `\(\_[^\]*\)` means atomic any characters including a new line, except for \\ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this line may work for you:

```
%s/^\\be\_.\{-}\\ee/\\begin{comment}\r&\r\\end{comment}/
```

Comment: Excellent! Building on your answer, I came up with

`%s/^\\be\n\_.\{-}\n\\ee/\\begin{comment}\r&\r\\end{comment}/g`

and to change it back

`%s/^\\begin{comment}\n\\be\n\_.\{-}\n\\ee\n\\end{comment}/\\be\r&\r\\ee/g`

Your answer identifies lines like `\begin{document}` as well, so I added some stuff to avoid that.

Thank you!

Comment: @user1577683 glad to help. you could upvote/accept the answer to thank me. ^_^

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I don't have enough rep to upvote it. Thanks again, though!